# How to optimize the response time for following Oracle 10g query?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, query-optimization, response

How to optimize the response time for the following query:

```
    SELECT
  /*+parallel */
  cc.customer_id      AS customer_id,
  cc.title1           AS title1,
  cc.forename1        AS forename1,
  cc.forename2        AS forename2,
  cc.surname1         AS surname1,
  cc.surname2         AS surname2,
  cc.company_flag     AS company_flag,
  cc.COMPANY_NAME     AS COMPANY_NAME,
  ext_customer_code   AS code,
  cc.customer_type    AS category,
  ca.address1         AS address1,
  ca.address2         AS address2,
  ca.address3         AS address3,
  ca.address4         AS address4,
  ca.address5         AS address5,
  ca.postcode         AS postcode,
  ca.postcode_prefix  AS postcode_prefix,
  ca.country_code     AS country_code,
  ca.town             AS town,
  ca.county           AS county,
  cc.client_id        AS client_id,
  cc.location_id      AS location_id,
  cc.data_source_id   AS dataSource_id,
  cc.SALUTATION       AS salutation,
  cc.ADDRESS_MATCHKEY AS addressMatchKey,
  ccv.vehicle_id      AS vehicle_id,
  cc.customer_name    AS customer_name,
  cv.REG_NUM          AS REG_NUM
FROM OEM.CDB_CUSTOMERS cc,
  OEM.CDB_ADDRESSES ca,
  OEM.CDB_CUSTOMER_VEHICLES ccv,
  OEM.CDB_VEHICLES cv
WHERE cc.client_id      = ca.client_id
AND cc.address_matchkey = ca.address_matchkey
AND cc.location_id      = ca.location_id
AND cc.customer_id      = ccv.customer_id
AND cc.client_id        = ccv.client_id
AND cc.LOCATION_ID      = ccv.LOCATION_ID
AND ccv.vehicle_id      = cv.vehicle_id
AND ccv.client_id       = cv.CLIENT_ID
AND ccv.LOCATION_ID     = cv.LOCATION_ID
AND cv.LOCATION_ID      = 1
AND ccv.rejection_flag  = 'N'
AND ccv.owner_status   IS NOT NULL
AND cc.client_id        = 1776
AND ca.client_id        = 1776
AND ca.country_code     ='UK'
AND ca.area_id         IN
  ( SELECT start_code postcode_id FROM MDB_FORMAT WHERE NAME = 'PC%1776'
  )
AND cv.model_id IN
  ( SELECT m.start_code model_id FROM MDB_FORMAT m WHERE m.NAME = '10_RWMOD'
  )
ORDER BY customer_name,
  town,
  postcode
```

Here's execution plan:

```
| Id  | Operation                        | Name                     | Rows  | Bytes | Cost (%CPU)| Time     |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   0 | SELECT STATEMENT                 |                          |     1 |   317 |   320   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   1 |  SORT ORDER BY                   |                          |     1 |   317 |   320   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   2 |   NESTED LOOPS                   |                          |     1 |   317 |   319   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   3 |    NESTED LOOPS                  |                          |     1 |   299 |   319   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   4 |     NESTED LOOPS                 |                          |     1 |   273 |   319   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  5 |      HASH JOIN                   |                          |     8 |  1992 |   314   (1)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   6 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CDB_ADDRESSES            |    10 |  1060 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|   7 |        NESTED LOOPS              |                          |   501 | 62124 |    30   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  8 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN         | MDB_FORMAT_PK            |    48 |   864 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|*  9 |         INDEX RANGE SCAN         | CDB_ADDRESSES_SMM_IDX1   |    10 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|  10 |       TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID| CDB_CUSTOMERS            | 28544 |  3484K|   283   (0)| 00:00:04 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 11 |        INDEX RANGE SCAN          | CDB_CUSTOMERS_UK1        | 28544 |       |    38   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 12 |      TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID | CDB_CUSTOMER_VEHICLES    |     1 |    24 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 13 |       INDEX RANGE SCAN           | CDB_CUSTOMER_VEHICLES_PK |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|  14 |     TABLE ACCESS BY INDEX ROWID  | CDB_VEHICLES             |     1 |    26 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 15 |      INDEX RANGE SCAN            | CDB_VEHICLES_PREF_IND    |     1 |       |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |                                                                                                                                                                                                
|* 16 |    INDEX RANGE SCAN              | MDB_FORMAT_PK            |     1 |    18 |     1   (0)| 00:00:01 |
```

Predicate Information (identified by operation id):

```
   5 - access("CC"."CLIENT_ID"="CA"."CLIENT_ID" AND "CC"."ADDRESS_MATCHKEY"="CA"."ADDRESS_MATCHKEY"                                                                                                                                                                                                          
              AND "CC"."LOCATION_ID"="CA"."LOCATION_ID")                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                     
   8 - access("NAME"='PC%1776')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                              
   9 - access("CA"."CLIENT_ID"=1776 AND "CA"."AREA_ID"=TO_NUMBER("START_CODE") AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                           
              "CA"."COUNTRY_CODE"='UK' AND "CA"."LOCATION_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
  11 - access("CC"."CLIENT_ID"=1776 AND "CC"."LOCATION_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                
  12 - filter("CCV"."OWNER_STATUS" IS NOT NULL AND "CCV"."REJECTION_FLAG"='N')                                                                                                                                                                                                                               
  13 - access("CCV"."CLIENT_ID"=1776 AND "CC"."CUSTOMER_ID"="CCV"."CUSTOMER_ID" AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
              "CCV"."LOCATION_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       filter("CCV"."LOCATION_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
  15 - access("CCV"."VEHICLE_ID"="CV"."VEHICLE_ID" AND "CV"."CLIENT_ID"=1776 AND                                                                                                                                                                                                                             
              "CV"."LOCATION_ID"=1)                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                          
  16 - access("M"."NAME"='10_RWMOD')                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                         
       filter("CV"."MODEL_ID"=TO_NUMBER("M"."START_CODE"))                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                   
41 rows selected
```

Comment: response time is dependent on many factors...

Comment: Could you fix the query formatting so we can read more than the SELECT?

Comment: Just fixed the formatting, sorry for an annoyance.  GREATLY APPRECIATE FOR FEEDBACK!!!

Comment: @Roman, what indexes are set up on the tables?

Comment: Are you defining response time as "time to first row returned?"  If so, adding a `FIRST_ROWS(n)` (for appropriate N) may change the plan.  Your `PARALLEL` hint is, on the other hand, working against that definition of response time.  And the `ORDER BY` clause forces Oracle to sort the output before you get a single row back in the first place.  How many rows (rough order of magnitude - tens, thousands, tens of thousands, etc) do you expect this query to return?

Comment: It returns about 18000 to 8000 rows depending on filter criteria.

Comment: So are you really trying to optimize response time (time to first row) or throughput (time to all rows)?  Also note that Oracle estimates the query to return but a single row once it's done with the hash join (step 5) -- is that a realistic expectation, or is Oracle overestimating the selectivity of your predicates?  (Google "tuning by cardinality feedback")

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Step 1: Make sure the query is correct.  I'm not sure what your data model is, but I noticed you say "SELECT start_code postcode_id" and "SELECT m.start_code model_id".  Do you mean to alias the same field for two purposes?

Step 2: Analyze the tables. Out-of-date statistics might cause the optimizer to chose a bad plan.

Step 3: Write your join conditions in the FROM clause (e.g., "table1 JOIN table2 ON (table1.id = table2.id)).  This makes it obvious to you, the optimizer, and anyone reading your code what you're trying to do.  It's easier to rearrange something that's already organized.

Step 4: Repeat Step 1.

Step 5: We'll talk about that when you've gotten there.

Answer (score 1):

Usually its a good idea to mask your customer's info, like change the company name to CO or XXX, you don't even need the schema name to optimize the query.

Comment: I'd agree with you, but in this case it's just one of the OEMs, like Microsoft, Oracle, etc. Point well taken.  Thanks a lot for stripping a point from my rating.

Comment: Strange behavior - when removing the number of columns (currently 28) to only 2 reduce performance (i.e. returning 18000 rows = 3.5 seconds vs. previously = 89 seconds).

Comment: @Roman Kagan: Why is it strange that removing columns from the results would result in faster execution? Fewer columns, less work all around. Chances are that removing the columns from the select list is allowing the query to use one or more covering indexes versus having to refer back to the table.

Comment: Those two columns are indexes indeed.  Thanks a lot for feedback.

Answer (score 1):

"It returns about 18000 to 8000 rows depending on filter criteria."
The explain plan indicates that it expects to return 1 row (and that's generally because it NEVER expects to return 0 rows).

I expect some of the cardinality estimates are wrong. One item that may confuse it is this

```
WHERE cc.client_id      = ca.client_id
...
AND cc.client_id        = 1776
AND ca.client_id        = 1776
```

Items 9 and 11 both have the 1776 filter, but then item 5 makes sure they match. This is redundant, but may be affecting the cardinality estimate.